# Stop ingestion into ADX

Tags: azure, adx

We have an adx cluster that had multiple source ingestion tables. We have deleted on of these tables and its corresponding mapping, but now receive countless ingestion errors of the cluster looking for this table. Does anyone know of the proper way to stop the cluster from trying to ingest to a deleted table, using a deleted mapping? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Azure portal go to Home > Azure Data Explorer Clusters > [your cluster name] | Databases > [your database name] > Data connections

Select the connection and delete it.